# Transmitting UART Byte during ISR on MSP430

Tags: c, uart, msp430, isr

I'm trying to figure out the best design practice for handling data in my ISR.  I know that I want my ISR to be quick, so is it OKAY to be sending data to the UART during my ISR?  Am I doing too much?

```
static void ParseRxData(const uint8_t rx_byte)
{
    // Only Allow ASCII Characters to be loaded into buffer
    // This will drop CR/LF etc, won't go in gRxBuffer
    if (rx_byte >= 0x20)
        gRxBuffer[gWrIndex++] = tolower(rx_byte); // stuff lowercase only into buffer

    if (rx_byte == 0x08) /* backspace */
    {
        UartSendChar(rx_byte);
        gWrIndex--; /* backup index to ignore previous character */
        UartSendChar(0x20); // space to clear old data
    }

    UartSendChar(rx_byte);

    if (gWrIndex == BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        gWrIndex = 0;
    }

    if (rx_byte == 0x0A) // End of Command
    {
        gRxBuffer[gWrIndex] = 0;  // Add null pointer to end
        gFlagCmdReady = true;  // Set Global Flag Ready Command
        gWrIndex = 0;
    }
}


//******************************************************************************
//
//This is the USCI_A1 interrupt vector service routine.
//
//******************************************************************************
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_A1_VECTOR
__interrupt
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
__attribute__((interrupt(USCI_A1_VECTOR)))
#endif
void EUSCI_A1_ISR(void)
{
    uint8_t RXData;
    switch(__even_in_range(UCA1IV,USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG))
    {
    case USCI_NONE: break;
    case USCI_UART_UCRXIFG:
        RXData = EUSCI_A_UART_receiveData(EUSCI_A1_BASE);
        ParseRxData(RXData);
        break;
    case USCI_UART_UCTXIFG: break;
    case USCI_UART_UCSTTIFG: break;
    case USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be making textual adjustments to the received data in the ISR, or transmitting. Buffer the data, and if necessary introduce another layer, that does not suspend other interrupts of the same or lower priority. You could be making them wait for a whole byte transmission time which is in MPU terms quite long.

Comment: Second that - Only do the *absolute minimum* of what needs to be done in an ISR. Even if modern MCUs are fast enough to do quite a bit of stuff in an ISR: The more you add to it, the higher the chance that you introduce hard to track race conditions, loose input or delay other ISRs. Put the received characters in a ring buffer or similar structure, and do all the high-level work in a free-running or blocking loop (whatever your platform/OS is providing) that waits for characters to appear there.